# How to handle css styling in source folder not affecting the html page in public folder in React projects

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Firstly, I **initialize** a **template React App** using `npx create-react-app my-app`

---

Then, I modify the project, and here is my **project directory** which `my-app` is the root:

- my-app

  - node_modules
  - public

    - `index.html`
    - `manifest.json`
    - `robots.txt`
  - src

    - components

      - `Main.js`
      - `Navbar.js`
    - fonts
    - images
    - `App.js`
    - `index.js`
    - `style.css`
  - `package-lock.json`
  - `package.json`

---

In HTML `<head>` I **attach a stylesheet reference** `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../src/style.css">` but it didn't work, how to handle this?. Notice that I am **not trying to** [**attach or import a stylesheet in Javascript (JSX)**](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-stylesheet/) file but rather **import CSS styling** to an **HTML file** but it seems the react app doesn't allow `index.html` to import the styling from another folder.

Answer (score 1):

Urls in `index.html` aren't processed by webpack in the same way as the imports in a JS file. If you want to add a reference to a plain, unprocessed asset, you could place it in the `public` folder and use `%PUBLIC_URL%` like so:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/style.css">`

The relevant section of the create-react-app docs is "adding assets outside of the module system": https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/#adding-assets-outside-of-the-module-system